# Is every Plaid transaction_id unique?

Tags: javascript, api, transactions, banking, plaid

Is every transaction_id received from a Plaid transaction call unique? Or do they need to be paired up with something else, like an account id, to be unique? Specifically, is there a chance that two separate users, from two separate financial institutions, to have the same transaction_id for two different transactions?

I tried looking this up on Plaid's documentation and on other forums, but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its unique across their platform and that's how its their in the documentation. In order to avoid duplicate entry in the database, its always good to have unique constraints on plaid transaction id and the account id(foreign key reference for the table you have the account details).

https://plaid.com/docs/#transactions